# Problem with React Native : watchman warning

Tags: react-native

watchman warning:

```
opendir(/Users/mahamadouniakate/Library/Caches/CloudKit/com.apple.Safari) -> Operation not permitted. Marking this portion of the tree deleted
To clear this warning, run:
`watchman watch-del /Users/mahamadouniakate ; watchman watch-project /Users/mahamadouniakate`

INFO
03:35
Opening exp://127.0.0.1:19000 in iOS simulator
ERROR
03:35
opendir(/Users/mahamadouniakate/Library/Caches/CloudKit/com.apple.Safari) -> Operation not permitted. Marking this portion of the tree deleted
To clear this warning, run:
`watchman watch-del /Users/mahamadouniakate ; watchman watch-project /Users/mahamadouniakate`

ERROR
03:35
opendir(/Users/mahamadouniakate/Library/Caches/CloudKit/com.apple.Safari) -> Operation not permitted. Marking this portion of the tree deleted
To clear this warning, run:
`watchman watch-del /Users/mahamadouniakate ; watchman watch-project /Users/mahamadouniakate`

INFO
03:35
Tunnel ready.
ERROR
04:42
We noticed your tunnel is having issues. This may be due to intermittent problems with our tunnel provider. If you have trouble connecting to your app, try to Restart the project, or switch Host to LAN.
INFO
```

Comment: Hello everybody,

Comment: I have a problem with watchman. My simulator IOS don't work because i have a error message with watchman. I have a problem with react-navigation when i start to use-it it don't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I had two directories called 'watchman', I don't know why this happened, **just uncheck** the repeated boxes in

Mac-> System Preferences -> Security and privacy -> Privacy

[image]

Answer (score -1):

For me this solution works:
Run these commands one by one -
$ watchman watch-del-all
$ watchman shutdown-server

Comment: This is not a solution, just a temporary workaround. The problem comes again in a few hours.